# Holo Everywhere and facebookSDK dont work

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-support-library, android-holo-everywhere

I'm trying to use facebook SDK with holoeverywhere but not working because the library android v4, it seems that libraries are not the same as sherlock facebook and then how to solve it? someone already implemented this?

sorry but my ENGLISH is bad.

Ty.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue using ActionBarSherlock and the compatibility library. What I did to fix it was delete the compatibility library from both my project and  ABS, then I right-clicked on ABS and did Android Tools->Add Support Library. After that, I also added it back to my project. Clean the workspace and errors went away. Hope this helps!